# How to implement notifications after a database update?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I've made 2 applications wherein the merchant requests a payment to the customer, payment is made by scanning a qr code generated by the merchant. How can I implement notifications after a transaction is complete or after a database update?

Comment: You can use push notification to implement this task.

Answer (score 0):

For implementing a notification, you have to implement socket which will emit event after the transaction is completed.

To know more about socket, visit [Socket.io Documentation](https://socket.io/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

i am sending the notification after update data in firebase message table:-

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("your table name").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (notify) {
                    sendNotification("New Message", firebaseUser.getUid(),receiver,
                            dataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue().toString(), msg);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: appreciate the answer if it helps you